# How to use range() when you want number with 2 digits only (01,02 ... 10,11)?

Tags: php, arrays, range

I have an array of numbers like that

```
$arr = range(01,10);
```

But I would like the output to be

```
Array ( [0] => 01 [1] => 02 [2] => 03 ... [9] => 10)
```

how could I do that ?

Comment: str_pad($x,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);

Comment: Don't try to store them in your array this way (for one reason, because of octal number issues). Store them in your array as regular integers and format them for _output_. As others have said, integers don't have a concept of padding. Padding is for strings.

Comment: A number does not have any concept of digits. That's a property of the string representation of a number.

Comment: Convert everything to strings and check lengths. That's the lazy way to do it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You probably need `array_map()`:

```
array_map(function($item) {
    return str_pad($item, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT); 
}, $arr);
```

[**Demo**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/x6nq4B)

Alternatively, you could use `sprintf()` too:

```
return sprintf('%02d', $item);
```

If the array is large, you may wish to perform the replacement in-place; thanks [Waygood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1487944/waygood) for the suggestion:

```
array_walk($arr, function(&$item) {
    $item = str_pad($item, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT); 
});
```

Comment: Good. A proper, concise solution. +1

Comment: ditto Colin, was about to suggest array_walk :-) +1

Comment: Is `array_map` really preferable to a `foreach($arr as &$item)` here?

Comment: @Eric They're different. One modifies the array in place, the other returns a modified copy of the original array. `array_walk` would be equivalent to a `foreach` by reference

Comment: @Eric It depends; given a big enough array, performing `array_walk()` or `foreach` with references may be preferred.

Comment: the first one doesn't work The one with &$item does work. should be `$arr = array_map(...`

Comment: @UnamataSanatarai What do you mean by [doesn't work](http://codepad.viper-7.com/x6nq4B)?

Comment: @Jack I'm a person who knows where to look for the answer not memorize the answer. array_map returns value, array_walk overrides it. Thus my "doesn't work". sorry for the confusion. Edited my "doesn't work" comment.

Comment: @UnamataSanatarai The `array_map()` expression by itself is the answer; whether it gets reassigned to `$arr` is up to the developer :)

Comment: what is & meaning, beside the $item?

Comment: @ssuhat it means that the variable is passed by reference instead of by value, so the assignment changes the variable in-place

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = range(1,10);
$arr = array_map('pad', $arr);

function pad($input)
{
    return str_pad($input, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
}

print_r($arr);
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/jGNCpJ)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [str_pad](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) option. You can use it to add leading zero's to your output.

```
foreach($arr as $key=>$val) {
  $arr[$key] = str_pad($val, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}

var_dump($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a foreach loop with references:

```
$arr = range(1,10);
foreach($arr as &$val) {
    $val = str_pad($val, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}

var_dump($arr);
```

Comment: Just didn't feel like using `array_walk`? It's faster

Comment: @ColinMorelli: really? That seems unlikely

Comment: Yeah, actually you're right in this case now that I think about it due to the overhead of creating the function call for `array_walk`